# How to download DGX from SDL AppStore?

Tags: dwt, installation

I'd like to download DGX from SDL AppStore. But when I try to download it an error occurs. And old Tridion World disappers so I cannot download it.

How can I get DGX?

Error is following:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've reported your issue to the appstore website owner and they will look at it as soon as possible, I'll keep you posted on the progress (once it works again I'll update my answer).

## update

The file path is corrected, it is tested and confirmed that download now is available again.